# Finding bogus data in a pandas dataframe read with read_fwf()

Tags: python, pandas, file-io, fixed-width, read.fwf

I'm trying to analyse the weather records for New York, using the daily data taken from here: http://cdiac.ornl.gov/epubs/ndp/ushcn/daily_doc.html

I'm loading the data with:

```
tf = pandas.read_fwf(io.open('state30_NY.txt'), widths=widths, names=names, na_values=['-9999'])
```

Where:

```
>>> widths
[6, 4, 2, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1]
>>> names
['COOP', 'YEAR', 'MONTH', 'ELEMENT', 'VALUE1', 'MFLAG1', 'QFLAG1', 'SFLAG1', 'VALUE2', 'MFLAG2', 'QFLAG2', 'SFLAG2', 'VALUE3', 'MFLAG3', 'QFLAG3', 'SFLAG3', 'VALUE4', 'MFLAG4', 'QFLAG4', 'SFLAG4', 'VALUE5', 'MFLAG5', 'QFLAG5', 'SFLAG5', 'VALUE6', 'MFLAG6', 'QFLAG6', 'SFLAG6', 'VALUE7', 'MFLAG7', 'QFLAG7', 'SFLAG7', 'VALUE8', 'MFLAG8', 'QFLAG8', 'SFLAG8', 'VALUE9', 'MFLAG9', 'QFLAG9', 'SFLAG9', 'VALUE10', 'MFLAG10', 'QFLAG10', 'SFLAG10', 'VALUE11', 'MFLAG11', 'QFLAG11', 'SFLAG11', 'VALUE12', 'MFLAG12', 'QFLAG12', 'SFLAG12', 'VALUE13', 'MFLAG13', 'QFLAG13', 'SFLAG13', 'VALUE14', 'MFLAG14', 'QFLAG14', 'SFLAG14', 'VALUE15', 'MFLAG15', 'QFLAG15', 'SFLAG15', 'VALUE16', 'MFLAG16', 'QFLAG16', 'SFLAG16', 'VALUE17', 'MFLAG17', 'QFLAG17', 'SFLAG17', 'VALUE18', 'MFLAG18', 'QFLAG18', 'SFLAG18', 'VALUE19', 'MFLAG19', 'QFLAG19', 'SFLAG19', 'VALUE20', 'MFLAG20', 'QFLAG20', 'SFLAG20', 'VALUE21', 'MFLAG21', 'QFLAG21', 'SFLAG21', 'VALUE22', 'MFLAG22', 'QFLAG22', 'SFLAG22', 'VALUE23', 'MFLAG23', 'QFLAG23', 'SFLAG23', 'VALUE24', 'MFLAG24', 'QFLAG24', 'SFLAG24', 'VALUE25', 'MFLAG25', 'QFLAG25', 'SFLAG25', 'VALUE26', 'MFLAG26', 'QFLAG26', 'SFLAG26', 'VALUE27', 'MFLAG27', 'QFLAG27', 'SFLAG27', 'VALUE28', 'MFLAG28', 'QFLAG28', 'SFLAG28', 'VALUE29', 'MFLAG29', 'QFLAG29', 'SFLAG29', 'VALUE30', 'MFLAG30', 'QFLAG30', 'SFLAG30', 'VALUE31', 'MFLAG31', 'QFLAG31', 'SFLAG31']
```

Now, the issue I have is that when reading in the data, there seem to be a lot of `inf` values, and those shouldn't be in the source data (the nearest thing in the data are `-9999` values, which represent invalid data).

Normally, if I were using `lists` or the like, I would print out the whole thing to find alignment errors, and work out which rows are affected, then look at the source file to see what's happening. **I'd like to know how to do the equivalent in pandas** so I can figure out where these `inf` values are coming from.

Here's the code which shows me `inf`s:

```
>>> tf[tf['ELEMENT']=='TMIN'].min()
COOP       300023
YEAR         1876
MONTH           1
ELEMENT      TMIN
VALUE1        -38
MFLAG1        inf
QFLAG1        inf
SFLAG1        inf
VALUE2        -34
MFLAG2        inf
QFLAG2        inf
SFLAG2        inf
VALUE3        -38
MFLAG3        inf
QFLAG3        inf
...
MFLAG28    inf
QFLAG28    inf
SFLAG28    inf
VALUE29    -46
MFLAG29    inf
QFLAG29    inf
SFLAG29    inf
VALUE30    -57
MFLAG30    inf
QFLAG30    inf
SFLAG30    inf
VALUE31    -40
MFLAG31    inf
QFLAG31    inf
SFLAG31    inf
Length: 128, dtype: object
```

Edit: Corrected column widths. Problem still remains.

Comment: Did you check your widths? I think the fifth column (VALUE1) may be width 5.

Comment: @SeanTater You're quite right - thank you. Making that change `sum(widths)` adds up to the right number of columns. However, the problem still persists even with that change.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, let's mock up some data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame(
    np.random.normal(size=(5,5)), 
    index='rA,rB,rC,rD,rE'.split(','),
    columns='cA,cB,cC,cD,cE'.split(',')
)
df[df > 1] = np.inf
df
```

That, for examples, should give something like this:

```
          cA        cB        cC        cD        cE
rA -1.202383 -0.625521       inf -0.888086 -0.215671
rB  0.537521 -1.149731  0.841687  0.190505       inf
rC -1.447124 -0.607486 -1.268923       inf  0.438190
rD -0.275085  0.793483  0.276376 -0.095727 -0.050957
rE -0.095414  0.048926  0.591899  0.298865 -0.308620
```

So now I can use fancy indexing to isolate all the `inf`s.

```
print(df[np.isinf(df)].to_string())

    cA  cB   cC   cD   cE
rA NaN NaN  inf  NaN  NaN
rB NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  inf
rC NaN NaN  NaN  inf  NaN
rD NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
rE NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

But that's not really useful. So on top of finding the `inf`s, we should stack the column index into the rows (unpivot, if you will) then drop all the `NaN` values. This will give us a nice summary of the rows/columns with `inf`s.

```
df[np.isinf(df)].stack().dropna()

rA  cC    inf
rB  cE    inf
rC  cD    inf
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for both of your answers. I'm going to work through them later.

Comment: superb - needed that badly!

Comment: for those who just need the list of column names(like me :）), you can try `list(df[np.isinf(df)].stack().dropna().unstack())`

Answer (score 0):

`np.isinf` will fail if you have `object` dtypes in you dataframe.
To overcome this:

```
with pd.option_context('mode.use_inf_as_null', True):
    is_bad_data = df.isnull()
```